# What is the name of this elm construct: type X = X {...}?

Tags: syntax, elm

I am trying to understand this Elm construct:

```
type Item = Item { name : String, data : String }
```

- It resembles a record, but it behaves very differently.
- It is useful for defining recursive data models.
- Unlike `type alias Item = {...}`, it does not provide a "constructor".
- I cannot find it in Elm Syntax guides.
- I cannot figure out how to access its fields:

```
> item = Item { name = "abc", data  = "def" } 
Item { name = "abc", data = "def" } : Repl.Item

> item.name
-- TYPE MISMATCH --------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

`item` does not have a field named `name`.

6|   item.name
     ^^^^^^^^^ The type of `item` is:

    Item

Which does not contain a field named `name`.
```

- How is this construct called?
- How do you access the contained fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [Union Type](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html) with a single constructor which happens to take a [Record](https://guide.elm-lang.org/core_language.html#records) as its only type parameter.

The fact that the type name and constructor name are both `Item` is a common idiom, but holds no significance. It could easily be any other valid constructor name:

```elm
type Item = Foo { name : String, data : String }
```

For practical purposes, it can be useful to use a type alias for the internal record type so you can more succinctly pull values out. If you move things around a little bit:

```elm
type alias ItemContents = { name : String, data : String }

type Item = Item ItemContents
```

You could provide a function that returns the internal contents:

```elm
getItemContents : Item -> ItemContents
getItemContents (Item contents) = contents
```

And now it could be used like this REPL example:

```elm
> item = Item { name = "abc", data  = "def" }
Item { name = "abc", data = "def" } : Repl.Item
> contents = getItemContents item
{ name = "abc", data = "def" } : Repl.ItemContents
> contents.name
"abc" : String
```